# Get nested JSON data from one to many relationships in MYSQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have two tables as follows
**user table**

| user_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | zia |
| 2 | john |
| 3 | raza |

**subject table**

| data_id | user_id | subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Math |
| 2 | 1 | Chem |
| 3 | 1 | Bio |
| 4 | 2 | Math |
| 5 | 2 | Phy |
| 6 | 3 | Eng |

when I am querying data i am getting results like this:

```
[
{
    "user_id": "1",
    "name": "zia",
    "subject" : "Math"
   
},
{
    "user_id": "1",
    "name": "zia",
    "subject" : "Chem"
},
{
    "user_id": "1",
    "name": "zia",
    "subject" : "Bio"
},
{
    "user_id": "2",
    "name": "john",
    "subject" : "Math"
},
{
    "user_id": "2",
    "name": "john",
    "subject" : "Phy"
},
{
    "user_id": "3",
    "name": "Raza",
    "subject" : "Eng"
}
```

]

*My query is as follows*

```
SELECT users.user_id , users.name , subjects.subject FROM users,subjects;
Where users.id = subjects.id;
```

the reuluts shown above are in such a way that we have a separate data row for every subject of one student/user.

*but actually i want to get data in follwoing way:*

```
[
{
    "user_id": "1",
    "name": "zia",
    "subject": [
        "Math",
        "Chem",
        "Bio"
    ]
},
{
    "user_id": "2",
    "name": "john",
    "subject": [
        "Math",
        "Phy"
    ]
},
{
    "user_id": "3",
    "name": "Raza",
    "subject": "Eng"
}
```

]

Here as you see that we have data in such a way that every student has all of its subjects in one row only or in nested json formate

**PLease help me in solving this question**
Previously marked as solved but not solved.

Comment: You are looking for `for` loop or some kind of `array_reduce`. Basically you loop elements and gather subjects based on user_id

Comment: @Justinas may you please explain it with full query example.

Comment: You should look for group concat and group by queries in MySql

Comment: @AbhishekSharma if you don't mind please may you help me in writing a query for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should try using group_concat in MySql to merge subjects in a single column and group by the user_id.

Something like

```
SELECT users.user_id , users.name , GROUP_CONCAT ( subjects.subject ) as "subjects" FROM users,subjects;
Where users.id = subjects.id group by users.user_id;
```

Expected output should be something like

```
[{
    "user_id": "1",
    "name": "zia",
    "subject": "Math, Chem, Bio",
},
{
    "user_id": "2",
    "name": "john",
    "subject": "Math , Phy"
},
{
    "user_id": "3",
    "name": "Raza",
    "subject": "Eng"
}]
```

You can then explode the subjects using `explode(",",$str)`

This is just an example, try to play around it. For reference you can look into [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-group_concat-function/).

Comment: but when i json encode it , it gives me a list of subs as a string with commas but i want a nested json ,list as i described above.

Comment: I have already mentioned in the answer to use explode function to convert that string in subject to array. Read the answer carefully :)

Comment: for example, you can do `explode(',', $result[i]['subject']);` where `$result` is the result of query and `i` is the index of result. This will convert subject to an array. i.e.
`"Math, Chem, Bio" => ["Math", "Chem", "Bio"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either through php or through mysql

**Using mysql**

```
SELECT
    users.user_id,
    users.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(subjects.subject) sub
FROM
    `users`
INNER JOIN subjects ON users.user_id = subjects.user_id
GROUP BY
    subjects.user_id
```

Result will be like

[image]

Comment: but after encoding it to json its converting list of sub data into a string. and I want to get a nested json list

Comment: how can i do this.? please help in this regard too

Comment: @ZiaUrRahman share your code block that fetches data from db and json_encodes